# Animated kinetic text and graphics on the web

Tags: javascript, animation

How can I create animated stylized text, as well as some other animated graphic elements such as seen in this video around 1:21:  https://vimeo.com/69200399

Can anyone help me start off, not help with a full code but just with things to research.

[image: Animated Stylized Text]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an advice forum nor a code writing service. Please make an attempt at your problem first so you can show us what you've done.

Comment: Motion graphics? http://mojs.io/ and http://processingjs.org/

Comment: @Soviut - How do you make an attempt unless you know what you're looking for?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Did you search for "loading animation", "folding effect", "motion graphics", etc? If you don't even know what you're looking for, SO is not the place to start; it's the place where you finish.

Comment: Also WebGL: http://webglsamples.org/ and https://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl

Comment: @Soviut I didn't search for anything, I already know what it's called. I am not the OP.

Comment: There's also `jQuery.animate()`, which is kind've of simple but easier to get started with, http://velocityjs.org/, http://paperjs.org/tutorials/animation/creating-animations/ and a favorite: https://greensock.com/

Comment: @JaredFarrish This question would fall under too broad. If you need something as broad as this, Quora is the place to ask.

Comment: @A.Lau - Closing a question and being nice about it are two different things. I voted to close, but helping the guy out is not against "the rules". We should keep in mind we're here to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but I think you should look into SVG.  It will render natively in-browser so will be of high quality.  None of the elements you're referencing have much complexity... just shapes.  The animation can be done via script.  There are also some tools to help you with animation tweening if that's the route you go.

Another way is to use a tool such as Adobe After Effects and render a video.  Then, you can use whatever effects you want and you will have a guaranteed look at the end.  The downside is that you won't be able to adapt to different screen resolutions, and the quality won't be as high because the animation will be rasterized before anyone sees it.  If you need transparency on the video, look into VP9 with alpha channel.